# Problem while opening a file in C on linux

Tags: c, linux, buffer

I'm having problems with my C program which works perfectly on Windows but not on Linux. I use the following method for reading line by line a file:

```
char * getLineOfAnySize(FILE* fp, size_t typicalSize, int *endOfLineDetected,size_t *nrOfCharRead){ 
char *line;       // buffer for our string
int ch;           // we will read line character by character
size_t len = 0;   // number of characters read (character counter)
size_t lineSize = typicalSize;  // initial size of the buffer allocated for the line
*nrOfCharRead = 0;

if(!fp) return NULL; // protection

// allocating the buffer
line = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*lineSize); // expected size of the line is pathHead to typicalSize

if (!line) return line; // protection, if we fail to allocate the memory we will return NULL

while (1) { // loop forever     
    ch = fgetc(fp);       // getting character by character from file

    if (ch == '\n') break; // end of line detected - breaking the loop 
    if( ch == EOF)  {
        *endOfLineDetected = 1;
        break; // end of file detected - breaking the loop
     }

    line[len++] = ch;     // store the character in the line buffer, increase character counter

    if (len == lineSize){ // we reached the end of line buffer (no more room)

        lineSize = lineSize + 64; // we have to increase the line size 
        line = realloc(line, sizeof(char)*(lineSize)); // line buffer has new size now

        if (!line) return line; // if we fail to allocate memory we will return NULL
    }
    if( (len == 0) && *endOfLineDetected){ // empty file
        *endOfLineDetected = 1;
        break; 
    } 
}


line[len++] ='\0';  // ending the string (notice there is no '\n' in the string)
*nrOfCharRead = len;

return line;       // return the string
}
```

The workflow of my program is the following: I gave in input a path, the file correspondent to the path contains in each line others file path that I read with the function above and put into a structure. On each i apply the KMP algorithm to get the occurrences of a string.
The problem comes in my program when I try to open the files that correspond to the paths I saved earlier:

```
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(list->path, "r"); 
    if(fp == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", list->path);
        exit(1);
 }
```

On the screen is displayed:

```
, exiting ...
```

This is so weird because of file opening problem the output should be:

```
Cannot open "list->path content", exiting. . .
```

Even though I don't know why it gives me this error while opening the path read from the input file. During compiling there's no problem. I was thinking about buffer problems derived by the function "*getLineOfAnySize*. I'm not a Linux user, I was just trying to run the program in order to make sure it will run on both OS. Don't think about design issues or logical issues because on Windows everything works perfectly. Big up to everyone who will help me! Please ask further information about the code if needed.

**EDIT:**

The content of the input file is:

```
/home/xxx/Scrivania/find/try
/home/xxx/Scrivania/find/try1
```

Note that find is the directory of the project.

The following is a sample of my program in order to make more sense of variable and construct:

**foo.c :**

```
#include "foo.h"

FILE *fInput = NULL;  
FILE *fp = NULL;
char *line1; 
char *line2;
int endOfLineDetected = 0;
size_t nrOfCharRead = 0;
char ch;

fWord *w = NULL;
fWord *wordHead = NULL;
fWord *wordTail = NULL;

fList *list = NULL;
fList *listHead = NULL;
fList *listTail = NULL;

fPath *pathHead = NULL;
fPath *pathTail = NULL;

fPosition *positionHead = NULL;
fPosition *head = NULL;
fPosition *current = NULL;

char * getLineOfAnySize(FILE* fp, size_t typicalSize, int *endOfLineDetected,size_t *nrOfCharRead);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

fInput = fopen(argv[1], "r"); //the file that contains the path of the file in which search.

if(fInput == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

while(!endOfLineDetected){ //read line by line the input file in order to save the path in a structure
    line1 = getLineOfAnySize(fInput,128,&endOfLineDetected,&nrOfCharRead);
    fList *node = malloc (sizeof(fList));
    node->path = line1;
    node->next = NULL;

    if(listHead == NULL){
        listHead = listTail = node;
    }else{
        listTail = listTail->next = node;
    }
}

list = listHead;

fclose(fInput);

do{
    fWord *app = malloc(sizeof(fWord));
    printf("Insert the word to search: ");
    scanf("%s", app->word);
    app->totalOccurences = 0;
    app->p = NULL;
    app->next = NULL;

    if(wordHead == NULL){
        wordTail = wordHead = app;
    }else{
        wordTail = wordTail->next = app;
    }
    printf("Do you want to insert another word? (Y/N): ");
    scanf(" %c", &ch);
}while(ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');

w = wordHead;

while(w != NULL){
    while(list != NULL){
        w->p = malloc(sizeof(fPath));
        w->p->fileOccurrences = 0;
        w->p->path = list->path;
        w->p->position = NULL;
        w->p->next = NULL;

        if(pathHead == NULL){
            pathTail = pathHead = w->p;
        }else{
            pathTail = pathTail->next = w->p;
        }

        fp = fopen(w->p->path, "r"); 
        if(fp == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", w->p->path);
            exit(1);
        }

        int countLine = 0;
        endOfLineDetected = 0;

        while(!endOfLineDetected){
            line2 = getLineOfAnySize(fp,128,&endOfLineDetected,&nrOfCharRead);
            int n = strlen(line2);
            int m = strlen(w->word);
            w->p->fileOccurrences = w->p->fileOccurrences + KMP(line2, w->word, n, m, countLine, w->p);
            countLine = countLine + 1;
        }   

        w->totalOccurences = w->totalOccurences + w->p->fileOccurrences;
        w->p->position = getHead(); 
        w->p = w->p->next;
        list = list->next;
        fclose(fp);
    }
    w->p = pathHead;
    list = listHead;
    w = w->next;
    pathHead = NULL;
}

w = wordHead;

while(w != NULL){
    printf("WORD %s \r\n", w->word);
    printf("TOTAL %d \r\n", w->totalOccurences);
    pathHead = w->p;
    while(w->p != NULL){
        printf("FILE %s \r\n", w->p->path);
        printf("OCCURENCES %d   \r\n", w->p->fileOccurrences);
        positionHead = w->p->position;
        while (w->p->position != NULL){
            printf("%d %d\r\n", w->p->position->line, w->p->position->character);
            w->p->position = w->p->position->next;
        }
        w->p->position = positionHead;
        w->p = w->p->next;
    }
    w->p = pathHead;
    w = w->next;
}

w = wordHead;

printf("\r\n");

freeMemory();
freeKMP();

return 0;
}

char * getLineOfAnySize(FILE* fp, size_t typicalSize, int 
*endOfLineDetected,size_t *nrOfCharRead){ 
char *line;       // buffer for our string
int ch;           // we will read line character by character
size_t len = 0;   // number of characters read (character counter)
size_t lineSize = typicalSize;  // initial size of the buffer allocated for the line
*nrOfCharRead = 0;

if(!fp) return NULL; // protection

// allocating the buffer
line = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*lineSize); // expected size of the line is pathHead to typicalSize

if (!line) return line; // protection, if we fail to allocate the memory we will return NULL

while (1) { // loop forever     
    ch = fgetc(fp);       // getting character by character from file

    if (ch == '\n') break; // end of line detected - breaking the loop 
    if( ch == EOF)  {
        *endOfLineDetected = 1;
        break; // end of file detected - breaking the loop
     }

    line[len++] = ch;     // store the character in the line buffer, increase character counter

    if (len == lineSize){ // we reached the end of line buffer (no more room)

        lineSize = lineSize + 64; // we have to increase the line size 
        line = realloc(line, sizeof(char)*(lineSize)); // line buffer has new size now

        if (!line) return line; // if we fail to allocate memory we will return NULL
    }
    if( (len == 0) && *endOfLineDetected){ // empty file
        *endOfLineDetected = 1;
        break; 
    } 
}


line[len++] ='\0';  // ending the string (notice there is no '\n' in the string)
*nrOfCharRead = len;

return line;       // return the string
}

// Function to implement KMP algorithm
int KMP(const char* X, const char* Y, int m, int n, int line, fPath *app){

int count = 0;

// next[i] stores the index of next best partial match
int next[n + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
    next[i] = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    int j = next[i + 1];

    while (j > 0 && Y[j] != Y[i])
        j = next[j];

    if (j > 0 || Y[j] == Y[i])
        next[i + 1] = j + 1;
}

for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < m; i++){
    if(X[i] == Y[j]){
        if (++j == n){
            count = count + 1; //conta le occorrenze della parola nella riga in input   
            fPosition *node = malloc (sizeof(fPosition));
            node->line = line;
            node->character = i - j + 1;
            node->next = NULL;

            if(head == NULL){
                current = head = node;
            }else{
                current = current->next = node;
            }

            app->position = current;

        }
    }
    else if (j > 0) {
        j = next[j];
        i--;    // since i will be incremented in next iteration
    }
}

return count;
}

fPosition * getHead(){ //rimette il puntatore alla testa della lista
fPosition *app = head;
head = NULL;
return app;
}

void freeKMP(){
free(head);
free(current);
}

void freeMemory(){

list = listHead;
fList *tempL = NULL;
while(list != NULL){
    tempL = list;
    list = list->next;
    free(tempL);
}

w = wordHead;
fWord *tempW = NULL;
fPath *tempP = NULL;
fPosition *tempO = NULL;
while(w != NULL){
    while(w->p != NULL){
        while(w->p->position != NULL){
            tempO = w->p->position;
            w->p->position = w->p->position->next;
            free(tempO);
        }
        tempP = w->p;
        w->p = w->p->next;
        free(tempP);
    }
    tempW = w;
    w = w->next;
    free(tempW);
}

free(w);
free(line1);
free(line2);
free(wordHead);
free(wordTail);
free(listHead);
free(listTail);
free(pathHead);
free(pathTail);
free(positionHead);
}
```

**foo.h**:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct fileList{
char *path;
struct fileList *next;
};

struct filePath{
char *path;
int fileOccurrences;
struct OccurrencesPosition *position;
struct filePath *next;
 };

struct fileWord{
char word[50];
int totalOccurences;
struct filePath *p;
struct fileWord *next;
};

struct OccurrencesPosition{
int line;
int character;
struct OccurrencesPosition *next;    
};

typedef struct filePath fPath; 
typedef struct fileWord fWord;
typedef struct OccurrencesPosition fPosition;
typedef struct fileList fList;

fPosition * getHead();

int KMP(const char* X, const char* Y, int m, int n, int line, fPath *app);

void freeMemory();

void freeKMP();
```

Maybe also the way I free memory isn't correct.

Comment: What's the content of `inputFile` or `list->path`? Does it have any drive letter or backslashes in it? And just because it works fine on Windows doesn't mean there's nothing wrong with the code. If there is any undefined behavior it could seem to work fine on one platform and die miserably on another.

Comment: I've edited the question adding the content of inputFile, the content of **list->path** is clearly written on the code. It contains the path of the file to open obtained from a line of the input file. @FredLarson

Comment: You should show your (minimized) code in a way that allows to compile and test it. Show everything what is necessary to reproduce the problem. Before trying `fopen(list->path, "r")`, check the values of `list` and `list->path`. Enable all compiler warnings and fix the warnings if any. Build your program with debug information (add `-g` to your `CFLAGS`)  and run it with `valgrind` to find memory access errors. Does `getLineOfAnySize` return a buffer that does not go out of scope when the function returns or is re-used on subsequent function invocations?

Comment: In order to run the code, you can just try to pass as argument the input file with some path inside using the _getLineOfAnySize_ function to read lines from the file.  The buffer is reused in a while-loop and freed at the end of the program. If you want to whole code I can link you my git repository. @Bodo

Comment: Are you sure you initial input file name is passed correctly ?

Comment: I do the following command: `gcc -o find.c find` and then `find path`. path is the input file name.

Comment: Beware -- `find` is a system command in Linux.

Comment: I know and I have already tried to call my program differently @FredLarson

Comment: I cannot even compile your collection of functions and code snippets. Show the code that uses your linked list and leads to `fp = fopen(list->path, "r");`. Compile with `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o find find.c`. Fix all warnings and recompile. Run `valgrind ./find path`. If `valgrind` is not available, install it.

Comment: I edited the question adding a sample of my program. I tried to use `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -o find find.c` and I fixed all the warnings. The error remains anyway. @Bodo

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It looks like your path names end in `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not a full answer, but a hint for further analysis.**

I tested the program with the input file contents as shown in the question and entered one or two words.

If the first file does not exist, I get an error message as expected:

```
Cannot open /home/yuripaoloni/Scrivania/find/try, exiting. . .
```

Then I modified the input file to list two files that exist on my system and get an error message

```
Cannot open , exiting. . .
```

I extended the code that tries to open the file to get more output:

```
       fp = fopen(w->p->path, "r");
        if(fp == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s, exiting. . .\n", w->p->path);
            perror("fopen");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            printf("Successfully opened %s\n", w->p->path);
        }
```

This prints

```
$ ./foo input                                        
Insert the word to search: foo
Do you want to insert another word? (Y/N): y
Insert the word to search: bar
Do you want to insert another word? (Y/N): y
Insert the word to search: baz
Do you want to insert another word? (Y/N): n
Successfully opened /home/username/tmp/try
Successfully opened /home/username/tmp/try1
Cannot open , exiting. . .
fopen: No such file or directory
```

Apparently your program tries to open a third file after the existing file names. `w->p->path` might be a NULL pointer or may point to an empty string.

The same error occurs when I enter only one word. I did not further analyze the error.

To find out why your program tries to open a file with an empty name, you can run it in a debugger or add more output to see how many loop cycles are executed when processing the lists and which data you find.

Comment: Good, thank you so much! I want to ask you one more question, you think that the methods `freeMemory()` and `freeKMP()` at the bottom of main are a good choice or should I free memory in another way? @Bodo

Comment: I solved the problem adding `if(endOfLineDetected) break;` into the `while(!endOfLineDetected)` loop and everything works correctly on Linux but not on Windows. @Bodo

Comment: @YuriPaoloni Run a debug version of your program with `valgrind` to see which memory areas are still reachable at exit. It will show you which options to use for full details. You probably don't `free` everything. I don't have the time to analyze your program.